# Disabling OK command in a codenameone dialog

Tags: java, modal-dialog, codenameone

I have a PIN dialog like follows and want to enable the "OK" button only when the entered PIN has at least five characters. On Android, it seems to work, but in the simulator it's unusable as the button seems to stay disabled; My listener gets executed, but `ok.setEnabled` seems to do nothing at all.

```
public static String askPin() {
    final String text = "Your PIN for ...";
    final Label label = new Label(text);
    final TextComponent pin = new TextComponent("PIN");

    // is this safe?
    ((TextArea) pin.getEditor()).setConstraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);

    final Command ok = new Command("OK");
    final Command cancel = new Command("Cancel");

    ok.setEnabled(false);
    pin.getEditor().onChange((x, y) -> {
        ok.setEnabled(pin.getText().length() >= 5);
        pin.getComponentForm().revalidate();
    });

    final boolean cont = Dialog.show("Your PIN",
       BoxLayout.encloseY(pin, label), ok, cancel) == ok; 
    return cont? pin.getText() : "";
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing it all wrong?

Side questions:

- Will the cast to `TextArea` work on all platforms (it does in simulator and on Android)?
- Would e.g. using buttons in place of the commands be better?

Answer (score 0):

We don't support enabling the command without setting it again as there is no binding between a command and a component it's added to. In order to implement this the button would need to add a listener to the `Command` and monitor changes to the enabled flag. This can create a memory leak as commands can be stored while UI is often discarded.

We don't support enabling/disabling OK/Cancel in the standard dialog. You would need to create your own `Dialog` instance and control the buttons within it on your own.

Comment: Concerning memory leaks, I surely agree, but I've just spent one hour trying to build a Dialog the way you do, but I can't. I may be missing many details, but `dialog#addCommand` seems to do nothing at all in the simulator (Android) and I needed to use the should-be-private `placeButtonCommands`, but it creates the components privately and I can't add a listener either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I could create a Dialog myself somehow, but I want to use the existing stuff as much as possible as otherwise I'd have to deal with all the platform stuff myself. And that's too complicated for someone who hardly knows what's iOS. `+++` *Actually, you can add a listener and remove it before the dialog closes.* Or please give me some  hints.

Comment: The reason we don't expose that is that we don't recommend people do elaborate things within `Dialog`. You don't need to go into the platform specific stuff, that code is 100% Java as you can see here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Dialog.java#L859-L908